# Python sorted() with lambda as a key

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to understand how the key and lambda works with sorted(). I'm trying to play with a word and sort if from the lower-case to the upper and vise versa, but can't get it to work.

```
s = 'Alphanumerical'
sorted(s)
['A', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'u']

sorted(s, key=lambda x: x.islower())
['A', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l']

sorted(s, key=lambda x: x.isupper())
['l', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'A']
```

When I changed the method used from "islower/upper" to "lower/upper" it also didn't give me the result I expected.

```
sorted(s, key=lambda x: x.lower())
['A', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'u']

sorted(s, key=lambda x: x.upper())
['A', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'u']
```

The only way I can ascendingly sort the letters from the a>Z (lower to UPPER) was:

```
sorted(sorted(s), key=lambda x: x.isupper())
['a', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'u', 'A']
```

Another example is, I want to sort a list of numbers ascendingly starting with the odd then even, but it also didn't work!

```
d = [1,2,30,0,2,3,4,8,1,2]
sorted(d)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 8, 30]

sorted(d, key=lambda x: x%2 == 0)
[1, 3, 1, 2, 30, 0, 2, 4, 8, 2]
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: I see it is working correct. Which part is confusing herE?

Comment: What order would you expect or achieve? As it is your question is unclear.

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's not from the lower-case to the upper

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ord`

```
asc = sorted(s, key=lambda x: ord(x))

"A" "a" "a" "c" "e" "h" "i" "l" "l" "m" "n" "p" "r" "u"

desc = sorted(s, key=lambda x: -ord(x))

"u" "r" "p" "n" "m" "l" "l" "i" "h" "e" "c" "a" "a" "A"
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord

Comment: This won't work, I need to sort the letter ascendingly but the lower-case should be coming before the upper-case

Comment: In that case, you have separate upper and lower case letters, sort them, and then merge.

Comment: upperAlpha = []
lowerAlpha = []
[lowerAlpha.append(x) if x.islower() else upperAlpha.append(x) for x in s]
lowerAlpha.sort()
upperAlpha.sort()
result = lowerAlpha  + upperAlpha